# Can I override a function in a function using a closure?

Tags: advice, closures

I want to build a modified version of the `occur` command that obeys to `isearch-filter-predicate`. I made some tests and I found that I can do it using a modified version of `re-search-forward` that I built:

```el
(defalias 're-search-forward-copy
  (symbol-function 're-search-forward)
  "Copy of `re-search-forward'")

(defun re-search-forward-ifp (REGEXP &optional BOUND NOERROR COUNT)
  "Modified version of `search-forward-regexp' that filters (skips) matches
according to `isearch-filter-predicate'."

  (let ((POINT (point)))
    (catch 'filtered
      (while (re-search-forward-copy REGEXP BOUND NOERROR COUNT)
        (let ((B (match-beginning 0))
              (E (match-end 0)))
          (when (funcall isearch-filter-predicate B E)
            (throw 'filtered (point)))))
      (goto-char POINT)
      nil)))
(defalias 'search-forward-regexp-ifp 're-search-forward-ifp)
```

This is my modified version of `occur` that obeys `isearch-filter-predicate`:

```el
(defun occur-ifp (regexp &optional nlines region)
  "Modified version of `occur' that filters (skips) matches according to
`isearch-filter-predicate'."
  (interactive
   (nconc (occur-read-primary-args)
          (and (use-region-p) (list (region-bounds)))))
  (unwind-protect
      (progn
        (advice-add 're-search-forward :override #'re-search-forward-ifp)
        (occur regexp nlines region))
    (advice-remove 're-search-forward #'re-search-forward-ifp)))
```

I copied the `interactive` stuff from the original `occur` command in `replace.el` but I'd prefer to have a cleaner definition. I mean something like:

```el
;; PSEUDOCODE (closure?):
(let ((re-search-forward re-search-forward-ifp))
  (defalias 'occur-ifp
    (symbol-function 'occur)))
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

This code seems to work, even though it's not a "closure":

```el
;; I need a copy of `re-search-forward' because it will be temporary adviced in
;; `how-many-ifp' and `occur-ifp' functions:
(defalias 're-search-forward-copy
  (symbol-function 're-search-forward)
  "Copy of `re-search-forward'")

(defun re-search-forward-ifp (REGEXP &optional BOUND NOERROR COUNT)
  "Modified version of `search-forward-regexp' that filters (skips) matches
according to `isearch-filter-predicate'."
  (let ((POINT (point)))
    (catch 'filtered
      (while (re-search-forward-copy REGEXP BOUND NOERROR COUNT)
        (let ((B (match-beginning 0))
              (E (match-end 0)))
          (when (funcall isearch-filter-predicate B E)
            (throw 'filtered (point)))))
      (goto-char POINT)
      nil)))
(defalias 'search-forward-regexp-ifp 're-search-forward-ifp)

(defun override-re-search-forward (orig-fun &rest args)
  "Temporary advice the `re-search-forward' function, overriding it with
`re-search-forward-ifp' to make it sensitive to `isearch-filter-predicate'"
  (unwind-protect
      (progn
        (advice-add 're-search-forward :override #'re-search-forward-ifp)
        (apply orig-fun args))
    (advice-remove 're-search-forward #'re-search-forward-ifp)))
```

Definition and advicing of `occur-ifp`:

```el
(defalias 'occur-ifp
  (symbol-function 'occur)
  "Copy of the `occur' function (to be) adviced to obey to
`isearch-filter-predicate'")

(advice-add 'occur-ifp :around #'override-re-search-forward)
```

I don't know if advicing a function to advice a function inside it is a good idea but it seem to work (I need more tests).